# Es posible acomodar estos objetos de forma responsiva usando bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Estoy haciendo este sitio responsive con bootstrap, pero no se como usar la grilla o los `@media` para que se adapte como en la segunda imagen. Debería usar javascript?

[image: imagen para dispositivo de 640x360 orientacion portrait]

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #000000">

        <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
            <div class="col-xs-6" >
                <img class="" style="margin-left:50px" src="images/logo2.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-2" >
                            <p style="display:inline;margin-right: 50px;">Desarrollo</p>
                            <img class="" src="images/desarrollo.png">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-2" >
                            <img class="" src="images/ilustracion.png">
                            <p style="display:inline;margin-left:20px;">Ilustración</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-2" >
                            <p style="display:inline;margin-right:50px;">Diseño</p>
                            <img class="" src="images/diseño.png">

                        </div>
                    </div>



            </div>




        </div>
    </div>
```

Y así es como debería lucir en vertical:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No recuerdo mucho bootstrap, pero creo que tiene algo para avisar a la grilla, que dependiendo el tamaño acomode una debajo de otra

Answer (score 2):

El [grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) de bootstrap divide el ancho de la pantalla en 12 columnas, para resolver lo que planteas no necesitas implementar nada en javascript/jQuery mas que utilizar el css y js de bootstrap y las asignaciones de clases de columnas correctas.

> **Caso 1:**
>   quiero que en tamaño large se visualice **todo en una misma fila**,
>   pero **al variar el tamaño** las tres últimas imágenes se muevan hacia
>   abajo

Si lo que quieres es que se visualice como en tu primera imagen pero que cuando se llegue a cierto tamaño cambie a la 2da, lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Definir para la primera imagen 6 columnas y para las otras tres imagenes usar 2 columnas, de modo que ocupes las 12 columnas
- Definir para otros tamaños, como `sm` por ejemplo, que la primera imagen tome 12 columnas (de modo que el resto del contenido pase a una segunda columna) y que las otras tomen 1/3 de cada fila, es decir `col-sm-4`

  **NOTAS:**
- Para visualizar el comportamiento presionar en [image: pantalla completa] al ejecutar el fiddle
- Le quite el background color para que se pueda apreciar mejor el comportamiento
- En este caso al pasar a `sm` se acomodan debajo tomando 1/3 del ancho c/u

```html
   <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
 </head>
<body>
   <div class="container" >
      <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-s-12" >
               <img style="margin-left:50px" src="https://i.gyazo.com/f3770b006e68da04b61b3670274dc954.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4" >
                 <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/a934f6d402b4916556935d97b2421baa.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4" >
                 <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/56ac9e837a731c1fff558e425efeb624.pngg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4"  >
                 <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/b96dce0ae524db8374b6f9b49d3a413f.png">
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

> **Caso 2:** quiero que la primera imagen ocupe todo el ancho y las otras tres se acomoden debajo

- En este caso lo que quieres es que la primera imagen ocupe el total del `container`, es decir asignarle `col-lg-12`
- Cuando asignas el total de 12 columnas no es necesario que agregues otra `<div class="row">` ya que lo siguiente que coloques va a pasar a la fila siguiente.
- Las otras 3 imagenes deberian ocupar cada una 1/3 del container, por ende serían `col-lg-4`
- Creo que es mas sencillo que tus imágenes tengan el texto incluído cuando quieres colocarlo vertical.

Partiendo de este esqueleto básico puedes agregar cuanto quieres que ocupe para los `md, sm y xs`. Por ejemplo, yo lo dejé que ocupe 4 columnas cuando el tamaño es `xs` para que puedas ver el resultado en el fiddle.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container" style="background-color: #000000; width:500px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6" >
                <img style="margin-left:50px" src="https://i.gyazo.com/f3770b006e68da04b61b3670274dc954.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4" >
          <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/a934f6d402b4916556935d97b2421baa.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4" >
           <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/56ac9e837a731c1fff558e425efeb624.pngg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4"  >
           <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/b96dce0ae524db8374b6f9b49d3a413f.png">
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no me equivoco puedes declarar la primer fila de 12 columnas con la primer imagen y aplicar una segunda con 12 columnas con las siguientes imágenes.

O si requieres que tu separación de columnas sea como las estas declarando, puedes ingresarla como barra lateral de 6 columnas e ingresar dos lìneas de 6 columnas vacìas del constado derecho.

Puedes observar unos ejemplos de templates en este link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_templates.asp

Comment: LiberatoL, bienvenido, sería bueno que acompañes con algún ejemplo lo que planteas como solución ya que no queda claro.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: #000000;">
      <div class="row content">       
        <div class="col-ex-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 sidenav">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <img style="margin-left:50px" src="https://i.gyazo.com/f3770b006e68da04b61b3670274dc954.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-ex-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-ex-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/a934f6d402b4916556935d97b2421baa.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-ex-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" >
              <img  src="https://i.gyazo.com/56ac9e837a731c1fff558e425efeb624.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-ex-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"  >
              <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/b96dce0ae524db8374b6f9b49d3a413f.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-ex-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-ex-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">Espacio en blanco</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Buenas noches.
Como complemento a mi aportación le dejo ejemplo de aplicación.